# Current day number - different computers, different days

Tags: javascript

I´m using [this function in About.com](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldayyear.htm) to get the today number in year (ex: 226). But i´m getting different results (correct and +1 day) in different computers, using [this calculator](http://mistupid.com/calendar/dayofyear.htm) i´m also getting the wrong +1 day value. But using [this one](http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/daynumbers.php) i get the correct day number. All computers i tested have the correct date, hour, timezone.

Ex. Now is 8 minutes past midnight, so i´m getting the correct day (226), but before midnight all day when it was supposed to be 225, i was getting 226.

I suppose the function is ok, so where the problem should be?

Thanks

Comment: Seems you are using online tools, they might be tied to the time of the server.

Comment: Is this a timezone problem? You're probably getting the day number according to UTC, but if you're, for example, East Coast US, then the day number you want is five hours behind.

Comment: My timezone is UTC, all computers i tested are in my house and in some computers works fine!. Javascript doesnt use the user date time? If i use `var daynum = (today.getDOY()-1);` i will get correct day in my laptop, but in my desktop i get wrong day.

Comment: Please post the code you're using here as well, instead of only linking to external resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused between client time and server time.. Website..

http://mistupid.com/calendar/dayofyear.htm is using javascript to calculate the day of year using following formula

```
var DayOfYear = Math.ceil((EnteredDate.getTime() - startofyear.getTime()) / one_day) + 1
```

However, second website (http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/daynumbers.php) is using the server time to calculate the day of the year.

**UPDATES to get number of days according to UTC time.**

```
Date.prototype.getDOY = function() {
   var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
   return Math.ceil((this - onejan) / 86400000);
}


function convertDateToUTC(date) { return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(),    
  date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(),    
  date.getUTCSeconds()); }

  var today = new Date();
  var a = convertDateToUTC(today);
  var daynum = a.getDOY();

  alert(a);
  alert(daynum);
```

Comment: I understand that, but why in my 4 computers with the same timezone using the About.com javascript function..i got 2 with the correct number of day and 2 with +1 day?

Comment: @user1320951 is it possible that 2 of your computers have different time zone settings? For JavaScript to correctly work with time, your computer must not only show the right time but also have the correct time zone settings. You can just type `Date();` in your browser's JavaScript console and it will show you what time zone you're in. Like mine says "Wed Aug 14 2013 02:50:58 GMT+0200 (CEST)".

Comment: In all pcs the timezone is set to UTC-1, but in summer the hour change and my region hour is the same has UTC. Between 00h to 01h everything was ok, returning 226, now its 02:00h the function var `daynum = today.getDOY();` returns 227, while it should return 226. From Date(); i get _[02:03:57.084] "Wed Aug 14 2013 02:03:57 GMT+0000"_ Its a timezone issue, so how i´m going to get always UTC time?